# Folder requests not being handled by ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, iis, http-status-code-404, httphandler, httpmodule

I'm attempting to write a custom HttpHandler in order to handle all of my 404 errors. The handler is catching and handling all file types that I've specified but for some reason it isn't handling requests for folders, i.e. if I put in mysite.com/foo/bar.html or mysite.com/foo/bar.aspx it handles it and shows the right error page, but if I enter mysite.com/foo/ it shows a completely blank page, with no source code or anything. Here's the code for the handler:

```
public class RedirectHttpModule :IHttpHandler, IHttpModule {
public RedirectHttpModule() {
    //
    // TODO: Add constructor logic here
    //
}

public void Dispose() { }
public void Init(HttpApplication context) {
    context.Error += new EventHandler(ErrorHandler);

}

private void ErrorHandler(object sender, EventArgs e) {        
    HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;
    application.Context.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
    Exception lastError = application.Server.GetLastError();
    HttpException ex = lastError as HttpException;
    ILog _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Page));
    string page = "~/404.aspx";
    if (ex != null) {
        application.Server.ClearError();
        application.Context.Handler = System.Web.UI.PageParser.GetCompiledPageInstance(page, application.Server.MapPath(page), application.Context);
        string username = application.Context.User.Identity.Name;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(username)) _logger.ErrorFormat("HTTP Error {0}: {1} Username: {2}", ex.GetHttpCode().ToString(), ex.Message, username);

        else _logger.ErrorFormat("HTTP Error {0}: {1}", ex.GetHttpCode().ToString(), ex.Message);
    }
    else {
        application.Context.Handler = System.Web.UI.PageParser.GetCompiledPageInstance(page, application.Server.MapPath(page), application.Context);
    }
}

public bool IsReusable {
    get { return true; }
}

public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
    if (!File.Exists(context.Request.PhysicalPath)) {
        throw new HttpException(404, String.Format("The file or directory {0} does not exist.", context.Request.PhysicalPath));
    }
    else {
        context.Response.TransmitFile(context.Request.PhysicalPath);
    }
}
```

}

and here's the relevant sections of the Web.config:

```
<handlers>
    <add name="html-to-aspx-isapi" path="*.html" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" />
    <add name="html-to-aspx" path="*.html" verb="*" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    <add name="htm-to-aspx-isapi" path="*.htm" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" />
    <add name="htm-to-aspx" path="*.htm" verb="*" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    <add name="asp-to-aspx-isapi" path="*.asp" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" />
    <add name="asp-to-aspx" path="*.asp" verb="*" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    <add name="RedirectHttpModule" modules="RedirectHttpModule" preCondition="" path="*" verb="*" resourceType="Either"/>
</handlers>

<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <add name="RedirectHttpModule" type="RedirectHttpModule" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
</modules>
```

For whatever reason, even though it's running Integrated instead of Classic, if I remove the first 6 handlers, it will no longer handle html, htm or asp requests with ASP.NET. I'm beginning to suspect there's some sort of configuration problem. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: Also, I'm curious why you aren't using the customErrors section of the Web.config for this.

Comment: Logging plus the fact that customErrors for whatever reason doesn't work correctly once authenticated, i.e. it gives the standard "server error in / application" page for any 404s. I suppose dealing with that issue would have been simpler, but this is a nice learning experience :)

Answer (score 1):

In IIS, set the default 404 page to point to your handler. What's happening is that IIS is handling the 404 before it ever makes it to the .net worker process.

Comment: How exactly do I do that? Do I just make it point to 404.aspx? Or is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Open IIS. Locate your Web site (application), and open up the Error Pages feature. There will be a setting for 404 error codes, simply open that up and have it point to an absolute url. Just make it /404.aspx

Comment: Curious, have you disabled <customErrors> since you are using this other method?